# Does encapsulating an "object factory" in a module pattern make object prototypes more memory consumptive?

Tags: javascript, oop, encapsulation

I want to encapsulate an "object factory" in the revealing module pattern to conceal variables, etc, from the rest of my program.  Do objects created by my module share the same `prototype` instance?  I.e., am I creating a new `prototype` object in memory each time I create a new object with my factory, or do all the objects share/"see" the same prototype?

Here is a simplified example of my code:

```js
var Factory = (function(){
  var uid_seed = 0;
  function TestObject() {
    this.size = 1;
    this.name = "foo";
    this.uid = uid_seed++;
  }
  TestObject.prototype.getName = function() {
    return "Name is: " + this.name;
  };
  return {
    testObject: function() {return new TestObject();}
  }
})();

var arr = [];

for (var i = 1000; i--;) arr.push(Factory.testObject());
```

When I create 1000 `TestObject` objects in the last line of this code, do they each have a prototype that is consuming memory?  Or is this a memory-efficient way of creating objects with a shared prototype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they do have the same prototype. The module initialisation code is executed only once, and only one prototype is created. You'd also expect that they all get different `uid`s instead of re-evaluating `uid_seed = 0` for every instance, right?

You can test that easily by checking `Object.getPrototypeOf(arr[0]) === Object.getPrototypeOf(arr[1])`.

Comment: you answered me very clearly -- I like the fact that your method to "test" does not require altering my prototype.  I do not understand your comment about re-evaluating uid_seed, though.  I checked and each `TestObject` I create has the desired `uid`.  I am using `uid` in an obfuscated way in my actual code; its inclusion here was perfunctory.  But am I missing something (ie your point)?  Thanks!

Comment: @Joshua: Yes, each object does have the desired uid. The `TestObject` constructor (and its prototype) and the `uid_seed` variable are in the same scope. If somehow each object was of a different class that is re-created over and over, and had a different prototype, that would suggest that also the `uid_seed` initialisation would have been re-run for each of them - and each object had the `.uid` 0. But it doesn't, which is just further proof your code works as it should.

Comment: Great!  Thank you.  Case closed.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: yes, they share the same prototype.

The slightly longer answer is you are only defining the "class" once. When you run the immediately invoked function expression to create your Factory object, that is the one and only time that function is run.

This means that your `TestObject` and `TestObject.prototype` are only generated once. A simple way of checking this would be to modify the prototype of one of your instances and see if it changes the others.

```js
var Factory = (function(){
  var uid_seed = 0;
  function TestObject() {
    this.size = 1;
    this.name = "foo";
    this.uid = uid_seed++;
  }
  TestObject.prototype.getName = function() {
    return "Name is: " + this.name;
  };
  return {
    testObject: function() {return new TestObject();}
  }
})();

var obj1 = Factory.testObject();
var obj2 = Factory.testObject();

// Original prototype function
console.log(obj1.getName());
console.log(obj2.getName());

// Modify the prototype of the first
obj1.constructor.prototype.getName = function() {
  return "Changed function";
};

// Both objects are affected
console.log(obj1.getName());
console.log(obj2.getName());
```